# XSD pattern for semicolon seperated list of double values

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there a way to specify an XSD pattern for semicolon seperated double values?

```
<test>2.5;25.2e7;-0.5e8</test>
```

This is my approach:

```
 <xsd:pattern value="[-+]?[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9][0-9]*)?(;?[-+]?[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*)*"/>
```

but I still find many examples where it gives me validation errors. If found things like [`\d+`](http://www.edition-w3.de/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502/), but it didn't help so far.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Do you only want to allow two digit floats or should more digits be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to allow two digits before and after the colon, all you're missing in your pattern is the exponential expression in the repeat pattern for second and following floats. You should modify you pattern as follows:

```
<xs:pattern value="[-+]?[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9][0-9]*)?(;?[-+]?[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9][0-9]*)?)*"/>
```

Or in a more compact version, also adding some parenthesis for sake of readability, and allowing for more digits before and behind the colon:

```
<xs:pattern value="([-+]?\d+.\d+([eE]?\d+)?)(;([-+]?\d+.\d+([eE]?\d+)?))*"/>
```

Which can be restricted to two digits before and after the colon:

```
<xs:pattern value="([-+]?\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}([eE]?\d{1,2})?)(;([-+]?\d{1,2}.\d+([eE]?\d{1,2})?))*"/>
```

Comment: Sure! Do you have a suggestion for extendig it to NaN as well? (as posted below to have more characters for explanation) Thanks!

Comment: I better open a new question for this to properly mark this question here as closed. Thanks for your help.